# order by budget high to low or low to high

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

for high to low:

```
$query="select * from sponsors order by budget DESC";
```

for low to high:

```
$query="select * from sponsors order by budget ";
```

When executing this query, it only orders by the first digit. For example:

budget: 
95,00,000
6,00,000
3,00,000
29,58,000
22,78,000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the budget values just numbers with commas in them?

Comment: no its not just numbers its like 6,00,00 p.a or budget ongoing ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to solve this problem is to re-architect the table and split budget into two fields, one int and one varchar which describes what the int refers to e.g. "p.a" or "ongoing" or "per month" or whatever. That way you can properly order your data by the int field.

In the interim, you should be able to order the data by stripping the commas out of the numeric part of the field and then casting it to an unsigned integer:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sponsors
  ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(budget, ',', '') AS UNSIGNED)
```

This should work as long as all the budget values start with numbers which may or may not contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

I think your column data type is char so please make ensure you use int datatype for column.

Comment: yes its varchar ,but when im using int so i can't use comma in btwn digits ..so its posible to use comma in int

Comment: You can use cast or convert function. ORDER BY CAST(column AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC

Comment: with int or varcahr ?

Comment: you can cast varchar datatype to decimal in select query.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.. this error is showing when i use this query

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY in ANSI SQL (you didn't specify your particular variant of sql; that would help :-) is dependent on the column definition.

If you want to order by numerical value (instead of string-based - if we're guessing, it looks like you have a char/varchar/text column here), you'll need to use a numerical column type, e.g., INT, FLOAT, DECIMAL, etc.

In other words, you need to tell SQL (via your schema) that you have numerical data specifically. 10 is only less than 3 in base 10. :-)

Comment: im using varcahr because the data is like 6,00,000 P.A

Answer (score 0):

You need to store budget as numerical datatype such as unsigned [INT or BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) in database.

For now, ORDER will treat all the data as TEXT. That is why they are ordering by first digits.

Comment: if budget is like 6,00,000 p.a ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
SELECT * 
FROM sponsors 
ORDER BY cast(budget as int)
```

if this is you column value (6,00,00 p.a)

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM sponsors 
    ORDER BY cast(LEFT(budget,length(budget)-3) as int)
```

Comment: from which type of data type i use with this query?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.. this error is showing when i use this query my datatype is int..